# Event Time and Watermarks can you explain it

Tags: apache-flink

I am new to flink, and am trying to learn the [Event Time and Watermarks section](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/dev/event_time.html#event-time-and-watermarks).

Can you explain what is Watermarks, and what problem it solves? The example is not clear to me.

does it only need for event time (out of order processing)?

Comment: There's already an explanation behind your link, which *does* -- at a casual read -- explain both what watermarks are, and what problem they solve. Unless you ask a more specific question that preexisting explanation leaves open (and ideally, speak to the specific aspects of the prior explanation that did and didn't make sense; ie. "I understand that watermarks put a boundary on event time, but why is this important?"), how is anyone to know that their new explanation will make more sense to you than the old one did?

Comment: I left an answer but I do agree with @CharlesDuffy that if anything my answer may serve to make things less clear as the Flink documents try to explain quite a bit what they are doing.

Comment: @zivroz I believe you can find good enough explanation on Data Artisans blog https://data-artisans.com/blog/how-apache-flink-enables-new-streaming-applications-part-1. For me it was easier to understand watermarks concept from it and relate to windowed processing, which is in essence how stream processing works in Flink.

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of the watermark is to define when a time-based window should fire.

Watermarks allow for the idea that events might be slightly out of order, so the time "extracted" from it might differ by some amount from where you would like to draw the "low water" mark for firing that window. For example if your data is generated from disparate sources that have varied latency before arrived (consider situation of distributed logging).However, you might not need this if your data is guaranteed to only have ascending timestamps, for example if it is generated from sensor readings.

So this goes hand in hand with the some of the [pre-defined Watermark generators that Flink provides](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/dev/event_timestamp_extractors.html#assigners-allowing-a-fixed-amount-of-lateness) which, not surprisingly, line up with the options.